# Can't use field name for have_rows() on WordPress ACF repeater fields

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

**have_rows() is not returning any rows for the field name.**

I have a repeater field on an option page.

Works:
`have_rows('field_554a52eedd894', 'option')`

Doesn't work:
`have_rows('advert_placements', 'option')`

The database entry looks like this:
`_options_advert_placements | field_554a52eedd894`
and those values are on the WordPress page too.

It seems to me that the ACF plugin isn't looking up the field name correctly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My issue was with caching specifically memcached. Once I configured that correctly this issue stopped happening.